# When dragging onto a table, how do you tell which row got dropped onto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I am hoping to use the 'Draggable' and 'Droppable' functions of jQuery-UI to drag data from one table into another.

I am hoping to be able to keep track of which cell gets dragged into (specifically, an X/Y index), and though the `This` object that the droppable function returns lists a `CellIndex`, which contains the Column (X) value, I've had less luck finding which *row* it got dropped onto (the Y).

How can I tell what row I just dropped on?

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/XcKdX/)

Comment: Got you started: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/uZZBx/ - just add your HTML and Javascript and save changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

- use [`drop event`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop)
- find the dropped object by using `$(this)` or `event.target`
- find the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) table row(`tr`)
- compare it to the table's rows by using [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

  ```
  $('#mappingChar td').droppable({
      hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      drop: function (event, ui) {
          var dropped = $(this),
              droppedRow = dropped.closest('tr');

          console.log(droppedRow.index());
      }
  });
  ```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/XcKdX/3/

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I'd simplify this a little to be `console.log(droppedRow.index())` and then `table` and `row` are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

you could use .index() or rowIndex to find that out, something like this in your code should do it:

```
$('#mappingChar td').droppable(
        {
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            drop: function( event, ui )
            {
                alert($(this).parent().index()+"\nor\n"+$(this)[0].parentNode.rowIndex);
                console.log('drop successful');
            }
        });
```